# Trying to get the Tag(String) of a checkbox control to a new form button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# and programming in general and trying to learn/practice a bit before starting classes in spring. Anyway I am trying to get the Tag of a checkbox control from Form A to Form B into a textbox on FormB (using string builder because there is other information from textboxes going to FormB Textbox as well) Now i can get this to work fine on Form B load but due to how my program flows i need to make this happen on a button click. Below is the current code that is working on FormB load. Sorry if i am missing something basic here.

Form B. I omitted some of my stringbuilder lines for space.

```
   public CodeBlueForm(List<string> ids, string custNameCb, string custWtnCb, string custCbrCb, string custNotesCb)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cbNameText.Text = custNameCb;
        cbWtnText.Text = custWtnCb;
        cbCbrText.Text = custCbrCb;
        cbNotesText.Text = custNotesCb;
        string checkBoxesLines = "Lights: ";
        foreach (string id in ids)
            checkBoxesLines += string.Format("{0}, ", id);
                System.Text.StringBuilder strBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            strBuilder.AppendLine("Inet Notes: " + "\r" + ((checkBoxesLines) + cbNotesText.Text));

            cbViewText.Text = strBuilder.ToString();
        {
```

My current Form A

```
private void code_blue_link_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkBoxIds = GetCheckBoxIds();

        tShootCb = tShootText.Text;
        svcsOfferedCb = svcsOfferedText.Text;
        otherNotesCb = otherNotesText.Text;
        custModemCb = custModemText.Text;
        //Opens CODE BLUE form and pushes text to it.
        CodeBlueForm cbForm = new CodeBlueForm(checkBoxIds, custNameText.Text, custCbrText.Text, custBtnText.Text, custModemCb + "\r\n" + tShootCb + "\r\n" + svcsOfferedCb + "\r\n" + otherNotesCb);

        cbForm.Show();

    }
    private List<string> GetCheckBoxIds()
    {
        List<string> checkBoxIds = new List<string>();
        foreach (Control control in pnlCheckBoxes.Controls)
        {
            if (control is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;

                if (checkBox.Checked && checkBox.Tag is string)
                    checkBoxIds.Add((string)checkBox.Tag);
            }
        }
        return checkBoxIds;
```

As i said this currently does work on Form B load but i need to figure out how to make it work in FormB button click. Any direction on this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to edit the textbox in an **existing** instance of FormB? Or do you want to create and show a **new** instance of FormB when you click the button?

Comment: @Jan Hi thanks for responding. I want to edit a textbox in an existing instance of FormB(i think). For example. Click on Button1 on Form A and it opens FormB. Click on Button1 on FormB and it populates textboxes on FormB from textboxes.Text and checkboxes.Tag on FormA. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a handle of FormA to FormB upon creation. All items that are on your FormA can then be accessed in FormB using that handle.

```
public class FormA : Form
{
    public FormA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormB formB = new FormB(this);
        formB.Show();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class FormB : Form
{
    private FormA parent;

    public FormB(FormA parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTextBox.Text = parent.myCheckBox.Text;
    }
}
```

In this example you have a checkbox called `myCheckBox` on FormA, a textbox called `myTextBox` on FormB and a button on each form. Each button has a method called `buttonClick` registered to the click event. The button on FormA creates and shows an instance of FormB and passes along a handle to itself (`this`). The button on FormB can then use the handle (called `parent` in this example) to access all controls on FormA **IFF** you made them accessible by changing the `Modifiers` property to `public`. (This is not a nice way to do it, but for the sake of simplicity I'd recommend to do it in that way for *now*. Once you understand the dependencies you should move on the create public getter/setter methods to encapsulate exactly what should be changed instead of exposing the whole control.)

Comment: Why start bad habits, it doesn't take much effort to do it correctly.